# angularjs $timeout and repeated calls

Tags: angularjs, timeout

In AngularJS, is it possible to call a function repeatedly(say every 20 minutes)? I tried $timeout, but the function will be called only once.

Basically I want to pop up a notification dialog every 20 minutes of inactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `$timeout` again in the function. If this is not possible, write a wrapper function like this:

```
function wrapper() {
  theActualFunction();
  $timeout(wrapper, 12345);
}

$timeout(wrapper, 12345);
```

Comment: i got $timeout is not defined

Comment: $timeout is a service so you have to make sure it is injected properly.

Answer (score 5):

New version of AngularJS uses $interval for this. See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$interval